# Click on an element which has a specific attribute value in Cypress

Tags: xpath, cypress

I am writing this code for an element that has an attribute value `"123"`. Since there are many products on that page with the wishlist button. But I want to click on the wishlist button for this specific product `id(123)`

but I recieve an error saying

> `cy.click()` can only be called on a single element.
> Your subject contained 53 elements.
> Pass `{ multiple: true }` if you want to serially click each element.

Can someone help here?

[image]

```
cy.xpath('//div[@id="filterProducts"]//div[@data-wish-list-entry-number]').then(thisProduct => {
  if (
     (cy.wrap(thisProduct)
     .invoke('attr', 'data-wish-list-entry-number')
     .should('eq', '123') ))
   {
     cy.wrap(thisProduct)
     .click()
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the HTML showing the attribute value 123?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the first of the list you can use `first`:

```
cy.get("value").first().click();
```

If is not the first but you know the element number use `eq`:

```
cy.get("value").eq(40).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `if()`, just add the attribute value `123` in the selector.

Same way as you have in `[@id="filterProducts"]`

with XPath

```js
cy.xpath('//div[@id="filterProducts"]//div[@data-wish-list-entry-number="123"]')
  .click()
```

with Cypress get

```js
cy.get('div[id="filterProducts"] div[data-wish-list-entry-number="123"]')
  .click()
```

also

```js
cy.get('div#filterProducts div[data-wish-list-entry-number="123"]')
  .click()
```